# How do I group by the price per unit with each of the months in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I have the following data
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJDS.png)

I want to group by the sum of Price per unit with each of the months.
Something like these I have done in excel.
[Expected Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJobd.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby()` method of the pandas dataframe like this :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Price per unit" : [8250, 4372, 965, 5799, 8465],
    "day" : [1, 16, 30, 1, 14],
    "month" : [3, 1, 1, 3, 1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby("month").sum()["Price per unit"]
```